# 'System.OutOfMemoryException' while sending large amount of data to webservice c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I get "Out of Memory Exception" while sending large data using web services. It works fine for small amount of data.
Scenario is like : 
Here i have entity class called clsMovie. Here user uploads large file more than 250 MB.this file gets converted to bytes of array and assigned to MovieData member of clsMovie class.
when object of this class is passed to web service with large amount of data(large bytes of array), I get "Out of Memory Exception".

Code is :

```
MovieResponse objM = service.SaveProductMovie(objMovieEnt);     // I get "Out of Memory Exception".


    [DataContract]
    [Serializable]
    public class clsMovie
    {
        [DataMember]
        public byte[] MovieData { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string MovieType { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int MovieSize { get; set; }

    }
```

I tried to use WSE 3.0 Tool but it is not supported in VS 2008 and also i googled a lot,but all in vain.
Anyone have solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any memory restrictions on an ASP.Net application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525894/is-there-any-memory-restrictions-on-an-asp-net-application)

Comment: Changing the webservice to use chunking (send it in parts of 1MB for example) should make this error go away. Using webservices and sending huge amounts of data isnt really the way to go.

Comment: @Reniuz : this is not duplicate of dat.

Comment: @CodingBarfield : how to send data in chunks?

Comment: Have you configured memory limits?

Comment: @Reniuz : yes i configured everything in web.config.

Answer (score 1):

Sending an array of 250 MB over a webservice consumes a lot of memory, you need probably 3 times 250 MB of free memory to handle the array. What will happen if you have 10 user uploading? Besides that is the size of your 250 MB file about 10 times the size if you make a soap message, which is xml and every byte is converted to a char + xml tags.

There are better protocols then a webserices to send large files, for example you can use ftp and send the name of the uploaded file over the webserices when the ftp upload is finished. Or make 5 MB chuck and combine the when the last chuck is there.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using Streaming operations. Take a look here :

[WCF Streaming: Upload/Download Files Over HTTP](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP)

Answer (score 0):

You could check your configuration file for a size quotas in your binding.

```
<basicHttpBinding>
   <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ForgotPasswordService" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
       openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
       allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
       maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
       messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
       useDefaultWebProxy="true">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
       maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
   </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

There could could adjust `maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"` to your needs.

But in **your individual case** I would preferably consider the streaming capabilities of WCF like here: "[Large Data and Streaming in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx)" (MSDN)

**[EDIT]**

Thinking about it, if you had hit the quota limits, the exception would most likely be different and tell it you like "The maximum array length quota has been exceeded" or something similar.

An `OutOfMemoryException` is might have more to do with the actual limits of at least one of the communicating systems. A possibly cause might be some **memory leak** stuffing data into RAM and not cleaning up properly (or fast enough).

Comment: i made this changes in config file but not working. I am using asp.net webservice not WCF .

Comment: there is no memory leak.i am unable to send bytes of array whose size is more than 128MB.